# Dealing with geometry that should be geography (bad coordinates)

Tags: qgis, sql, sql-server, ogr2ogr

I'm working on a project with a few publicly available datasets. One of them is from the USGS, it's their prediction of peak ground acceleration in 50 years. [Here's a link](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/products/conterminous/), and here's what it looks like loaded into QGIS:

[image]

The problem is that the "coordinates" of San Diego, California are (roughly) -1,700,000 by 3,000,000.

The real data I'm working with is stored in SQL Geography, in a SQL Server, with SRID 4328 matched up real-world latitude and longitude.

My question is, especially since I've seen a lot of this type of who-knows-geometry going on, **how do I mesh up geography with weird geometry?** I'm using OGR2OGR to convert from shapefiles, in this case.

Comment: It's unlikely the USGS wouldn't say what projection was being used.  If you edit the question to add a link to the data, or include the projection file (.prj) content, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Vince link added in the question, and here for reference: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/products/conterminous/

Comment: @Vince in this question ( http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30613/why-is-my-prj-file-not-being-read-by-qgis ) it's stated that QGIS will read the .prj file automatically when it loads the shapefile. It's in the right directory, I'm looking at it with notepad open. So now I have the projection, but curious why QGIS didn't set it up that way from the beginning and went with project defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data appears to be in the following coordinate system based on the files I found [here](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/products/conterminous/).

You need to reproject/transform all of your data to be in the same coordinate system, whether it be on the fly in GIS software, or permanently in the data itself.

> **Clarke_1866_Albers**
>
> Authority: Custom
>
> Projection: Albers, False_Easting: 0.0, False_Northing: 0.0,
>   Central_Meridian: -95.0, Standard_Parallel_1: 29.5,
>   Standard_Parallel_2: 45.5, Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.0, Linear Unit: Meter
>   (1.0)
>
> Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Clarke_1866
>
> Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433), Prime Meridian: Greenwich
>   (0.0), Datum: D_Clarke_1866,   Spheroid: Clarke_1866,
>       Semimajor Axis: 6378206.4,
>       Semiminor Axis: 6356583.799998981,
>       Inverse Flattening: 294.9786982

Comment: thanks, I think you've got me on the right track. I'm in QGIS trying to set the projection for the layer but can't seem to find the one referenced there.

Comment: The definition is not in EPSG nor it is an Esri one.

Comment: Why the USGS is distributing data using the Clarke 1866 datum is beyond me... I understand using the Albers projection, but not sure why they couldn't use the NAD83 or WGS84 datums to be consistent with most other data sources.